# What are the most common errors faced by a beginer while using mathematica? any precautions to avoid them?

Tags: warning-messages, error-propagation

I would like to know the errors basically faced by beginners while using Mathematica. Are there any precautions or any lookouts to avoid or verify these errors while using mathemetica.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica S.E. To start: 1) take the [introductory tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), since the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) consider accepting the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking checkmark sign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: You can have a look at this famous thread [**`What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?`**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users)

Comment: A final comment: the way that you have posed your question is too broad. This type of questions get closed. This is by no means a punishment; it's just site maintenance. Please, do not get discouraged by that. Consider presenting to us a concrete problem that you are facing and many of us here, will be happy to try and help you out.